# Missing dependency cause infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am new to react and im trying to understand how to use the hook "useState()".
So here is my problem, i have a useState() list of object with two string, a char and a color. I set the string color in the className of my element.

Then my purpose is to change the color of the char depending of what i type into my input. But i understand there is a delay for useState(), it's returning the changed value one value late...
Then i need "useEffect()" so here is my code maybe it's more clear to you:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
const [words, setWords] = useState([{str: 'A', color: 'color-one'}, {str: "B", color:"color-one"}, {str: "C", color: "color-one"}]);

    const inputHandler =(event) =>{
        const string = event.target.value;
        setInputValue(string);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const charWords = words.map(word => word.str);
        const charInput = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length-1);
        if(charInput === charWords[inputValue.length-1]){
            const goodAnswer = words.map((elem,i)=>{
                if(i === inputValue.length-1){
                    return {...elem, color: "color-two",}
                }else{
                    return elem;
                }
            })
            setWords(goodAnswer);
        }else{
            if(charInput ===""){

            }else{
                const wrongAnswer = words.map((elem,i)=>{
                if(i === inputValue.length-1){
                    return {...elem, color: "wrong-answer",}
                }else{
                    return elem;
                }
            })
            setWords(wrongAnswer);
            }
        }
    }, [inputValue])

    return(
        <div>
        {words.map((elem)=>(
            <label className={elem.color}>{elem.str}</label>
        ))}   
        <input value={inputValue} onChange={inputHandler}/>
                
        </div>
    )
}
export default TestComponent;
```

So the code is working fine. The problem is the console say:

```
"Line 39:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'words'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"
```

But the problem, if i put my state "words" in my dependency array, i have infinite loop.

So here is my question, how to solve this "problem", maybe i do something wrong, or maybe i can let the warning in the compiler..

Thank you for the answers.

**Edit:**
I tried something new i create a new useSate like a copy of my array object. And in my useEfect, i set this state and now i can add "words" into my array dependencies.
But the problème now, when i change the value i add too the previous objects of the non-modified useState.

```
 if(charInput === charWords[inputValue.length-1]){
    const goodAnswer = words.map((elem,i)=>{
        if(i === inputValue.length-1){
           return{...elem, color: "color-two",};
         }else{
            //here it return the "normal-color" because my useState named "words" has not change...
            return elem;
          }
  })
  setUpdatedWords(goodAnswer);
```

So how can i fix this now ? :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i finnaly found a solution with the magic hook nammed "useReducer". I'm still verry confused about how to use it but it works, so here is my finnal code:

```
import "./test.styles.scss"
import { useEffect, useReducer, useState } from "react";

const reducer = (state, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case "good-answer":
            return state.map((elem,i) =>{
                if(i === action.id){
                    return{...elem, color: "color-two"};
                }else{
                    return elem;
                }
            });
        case "wrong-answer":
            return state.map((elem,i) =>{
                if(i === action.id){
                    return{...elem, color: "color-three"};
                }else{
                    return elem;
                }
            });
        default:
            throw new Error("l'acion "+action.type + "n'existe pas");
    }
}

const TestComponent = () =>{
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('');
    const [words] = useState([{str: 'A', color: 'color-one'}, {str: "B", color:"color-one"}, {str: "C", color: "color-one"}]);
    const [updateWords, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, words);
    
    const inputHandler =(event) =>{
        const string = event.target.value;
        setInputValue(string);
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        const charWords = words.map(word => word.str);
        const charInput = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length-1);

        if(charInput === charWords[inputValue.length-1]){
            dispatch({type: "good-answer", id: inputValue.length-1});
        }else{
            if(charInput ===""){
    
            }else{
            dispatch({type: "wrong-answer", id:  inputValue.length-1});
        }
    }
    }, [inputValue, words]);
    
    return(
        <div>
            {updateWords.map((elem)=>(
                <label className={elem.color}>{elem.str}</label>
            ))}   
            <input value={inputValue} onChange={inputHandler}/>
        </div>
    )
}
export default TestComponent;
```

I don't know if it's the best way to do this, but my "warning" has gone, and it's working well so...
Thank you to everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options for a solution:

1. use [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) for the words object - it will memorize the value so it will trigger useEffect only when the object values are changing.
2. change the words state to be a simple string array or split it

Comment: Maybe i don't use the proper way, but it's the same with useMemo. "Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders."

Comment: show me the code @fang44z

Comment: I try to figure it out, i've tried many differents ways with useMemo(). Everything that i can find or imagine. I returned the value of my state with a useMemo, i tried to create new useState inside my useMemo (i don't konw how to update it), and alot of other things but no success :(.

Answer (score 0):

Declare both the const values outside the useEffect

```
    const charWords = words.map(word => word.str);
    const charInput = inputValue.charAt(inputValue.length-1);
    useEffect(()=>{
    if(charInput === charWords[inputValue.length-1]){
        const goodAnswer = words.map((elem,i)=>{
            if(i === inputValue.length-1){
                return {...elem, color: "color-two",}
            }else{
                return elem;
            }
        })
        setWords(goodAnswer);
    }else{
        if(charInput ===""){

        }else{
            const wrongAnswer = words.map((elem,i)=>{
            if(i === inputValue.length-1){
                return {...elem, color: "wrong-answer",}
            }else{
                return elem;
            }
        })
        setWords(wrongAnswer);
        }
    }
}, [inputValue])
```

Comment: Now it ask me to include all the dependencies: ` React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'charInput', 'charWords', and 'words'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react`